# Document.evaluate for documents without namespaceURI crashes Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, xml, xmldocument, microsoft-edge

Tested on Microsoft Edge from Windows 10 build 10240. Fixed in build 10586.

**Synopsis**

Running `XMLDocument.prototype.evaluate` on a document that has `namespaceURI` set to `null` crashes the current tab process in Microsoft Edge, leaves the developer tools for that tab unresponsive, sends debug information to `watson.telemetry.microsoft.com`, and force-reloads the page.

**Repro**

To reproduce, open any website in Microsoft Edge, hit F12 to open developer tools, select Console, and run these 3 lines of javascript:

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
var node = doc.createElement('A');
doc.evaluate('B', node, doc.createNSResolver(doc), 9, null);
```

Comment: Windows 10 (build 10856) was released recently; please apply this update to see if the issue continues to exist. I'm on a later build, and am unable to reproduce the crash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Workaround**

Access the `baseURI` property of the context node before running `evaluate`.

```
var doc = document.implementation.createDocument(null, null, null);
var node = doc.createElement('A');

node.baseURI; // Edge workaround http://stackoverflow.com/q/33887400/823663

doc.evaluate('B', node, doc.createNSResolver(doc), 9, null);
```